# How many non-empty subsets of $\{ 1 , 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 \}$ consist entirely of odd numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

> How many non-empty subsets of $\{ 1 , 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 \}$ consist entirely of odd numbers?

Is my reasoning correct if I say that I have $2^4$ choices either to pick one of the $4$ odd integers in $\{ 1 , 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 \}$ to be in the constructed set and since there is the possibility that we pick none we just subtract the empty set and get that the answer is $2^4 -1 = 15$?

Comment: Yeah, that looks good.

Comment: Why subtracting the empty set? It does not contain elements that are not odd.

Comment: @Vera, because the problem statement mentions "non empty subsets"

Comment: @SolubleFish Oh, I see now. In fact a pity that this constraint is there. The question would IMV be nicer without it. An extra training on "vacuously true".

Comment: @Vera Although technical valid, it is strange to say that the empty set consists of only odd numbers. So, I am with the way the exercise is presented here. I could also say : "All planes I have are Pipers". Since I have no plane , this is a true statement , but everyone would conclude from this statement that I must have planes.